# JavaScript set boolean by separate conditions?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I need to design a global boolean with 2 conditions a and b such that if A is ever true, the boolean is true until b is true, at which point the boolean is false. In other words, if A becomes false the boolean remains true.

I tried a straightforward global variable but it became false when A became false.

Preferably JavaScript, but pseudocode would be almost as helpful.

Comment: You need to put some logic in your setter and probably need some other variables too.

Comment: Sorry I'm slow but I'm not seeing it. Any additional variables I make would be dependent on the first variable, which would be dependent on A and therefore false when A is false?

Comment: Sounds like the logic equivalent of a flip-flop circuit.

Comment: Is there only one A and one B or does this need to be re-used?

Comment: I believe flip-flop is correct. Yes, only one a and b

Comment: Your spec is not completely defined. What happens if A has never been true, in response to B?

Comment: Nothing. B is independent of the system except for causing the global bool to be false.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an XOR. i.e.

```
!A and !B == false
A and !B == true
!A and B == true
A and B == false
```

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't have a logical XOR operator, however

if( A ? !B : B ) {

is functionally equivalent

Comment: `!!(A ^ B)` should work since false is converted to `0` and true to `1` and then the result is converted back to boolean. In fact: `!!(true^true)
false
!!(true^false)
true
!!(false^true)
true
!!(false^false)
false`

Answer (score 2):

Javascript old-school way:

```
function Enjoy() {
    this.a = true;
    this.b = true;
    this.bool = true;
}

Enjoy.prototype = {
    constructor: Enjoy,

    setA: function( val ) {
        this.a = val;
        if ( this.a === true && this.b === true ) this.bool = false;
        else if ( this.a === true && this.b === false ) this.bool = true;
    },

    setB: function( val ) {
        this.b = val;
        if ( this.a === true && this.b === true ) this.bool = true;
        else if ( this.a === true && this.b === false ) this.bool = false;
    },

    getBool: function() {
        return this.bool;
    }
};

var enjoy = new Enjoy();
enjoy.getBool(); // true
enjoy.setB( false );
enjoy.getBool(); // false
```

As you can see, the idea is to use getters/setters for your boolean and both `a` and `b` variables where you do all your logic.

By the way, this question is definitely for StackOverflow.

Comment: This looks like it might work, I will test it shortly. Many thanks!

Comment: Since `this.a` and `this.b` are *never* set, except in the constructor, this code will not work.

Comment: But doesnt the setting happen in 'enjoy.setB( false )'?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be fairly easy to match those cases with

```
var bool = (a != b);
/*
    (false != false) = false
    (true != false) = true
    (false != true) = true
    (true != true) = false
*/
```

With your changes, you could create a global variable `var aWasEverTrue = a;` and then instead of setting `a` directly, use a function such as `setA(true)`.

```
var a = false;
var b = false;
var aWasEverTrue = a;
function setA(newAValue) {
    aWasEverTrue = true;
    a = newAValue;
}

// (aWasEverTrue != b) = false

setA(true);
// (aWasEverTrue != b) = true

b = true;
// (aWasEverTrue != b) = false

setA(false);
// (aWasEverTrue != b) = false (as aWasEverTrue is still true)

b = false
// (aWasEverTrue != b) = true
```

Comment: This only works if both are booleans... You can do (!a != !b) to attempt a coercion.

Comment: Again, the trouble with these answers is that they disregard the time element. I need to know if A was _ever_ true before I test for B. In other words, it might be false now, but if it was true at some earlier point I should test for B. If B is true the global bool is false. Thanks for the interest tho.

Comment: sorry, didn't read this accurately; this is actually wrong in the third case. Any case in which B is true must be false.

Comment: What about `(aWasEverTrue && !b)` ?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a state machine

States for result:

```
T (True)
F (False)
```

Transitions:

```
F -- a (true) --> T
F -- anything else --> F
T -- b (true) --> F
T -- anything else --> T
```

You can express it with a series of `if`s

Answer (score 0):

Based on some assumptions about how B should behave if A has not been true:

```
function FlipFlop(){
    this.latch = false;
    this.value = false;
}

FlipFlop.prototype = {
    constructor: FlipFlop,

    setA: function( val ) {
        this.latch = this.latch || !!val;
        this.value = this.latch;
    },

    setB: function( val ) {
        if(this.latch && !!val) {
            this.latch = false;
        }
        this.value = !val;
    },

    getVal: function() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the colon after getVal? Sorry if this is a gimme, and thanks in advance

Comment: Another question would be: "What is this `||=` operator?" :-)

Comment: Do you know what || does? Compare to + and +=. The colon is for the key: value syntax for object literals. It defines a member named 'getVal' on the object that is being assigned.

Comment: the trailing colon is not required, but will not break anything if it is included. Many developers include it so adding methods or properties to the object later will be easier and they will not have to think about adding a colon to the (previously) last line.

Comment: and `||=` is not a valid operator, and using OR and EQUALS together like this throws: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = `

Comment: @rlemon: Ooops! Too much time Perling instead of Javascripting. Resolved